# When I transition to a new scene, that scene no longer works (one transitioned too)!

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This is my code here.. beginning on touches began!

```
if nodeITapped.name == "leftButton" {
    leftb.alpha = 0.5
    let fadeInAction = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1)
    leftb.runAction(fadeInAction)
    let sceneToMoveTo = MainScene(size: self.size)
    sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
    let myTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2)
    self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
}
```

Comment: Define "no longer works"?

Comment: The functions and actions performed in the next scene don't work like they usually do @ Whirlwind